# How to set your Flash message where to display? I can't seem to figure out

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.6

in my ContactsController I have add method/action and I set a flash message if successfully added a contact. and redirect it to index.ctp

```
public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('POST')) {
            $this->Contact->create();
            if ($this->Contact->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Contact added successfully!');
                $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index')); 
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Sorry! Contact is not added.');
            }
        }
    }
```

When I successfully added a contact there is to flash message display. But when I go to add view the Flash message is displayed. Please help!

```
<?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
    <h3>Address Book</h3>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Zip Code</th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach ($contacts as $contact): ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <?php 
            /*echo $this->Html->link($contact['Contact']['firstname']." "
                .$contact['Contact']['lastname'], 
                array('controller' => 'contacts', 'action' => 'view',
                    $contact['Contact']['id'])); */
            echo $this->Html->link($contact['Contact']['firstname']." "
                .$contact['Contact']['lastname'],
                array('action' => 'view', $contact['Contact']['id']));
            ?>
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $contact['Contact']['email']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $contact['Contact']['address1']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $contact['Contact']['city']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $contact['Contact']['state']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $contact['Contact']['zip']; ?></td>
            <!--<td><?php echo $this->HTML->link('Edit', array('action'=>'update',
                $contact['Contact']['id'])) ?>
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $this->HTML->link('Delete', array('action'=>'delete',
                $contact['Contact']['id'])) ?>
            </td>-->
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        <?php unset($contact) ?>
    </table>
    <?php echo $this->Html->link('Add Contact', array('action'=>'add')) ?>
```

Comment: You should echo your flash message somewhere in your main layout.

Comment: <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?> something like this? yes i did echo it in my index.ctp

Comment: Not there, in your default.ctp file located in `Layouts` folder.

Comment: I also echo it there. What i want is after adding data successfully i want the flash message to display in my index.ctp file

Comment: @PHP.Newbie if you use `setFlash()` it will render the message on the next page request wherever the first occurrence of `<?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>` is. Is this not happening for you or are you after something different? If you were to go to a different page after submitting the data (even if that's to open a new page in a different tab before the redirect takes place) the flash message will be rendered on that one. This is how Cake's flash messages work.

Comment: Make sure you have included the *Session* in components, 

`public $components = array('Paginator', 'Session');`